# How to insert a label in front of a button in dat.gui?

Tags: javascript, button, label, dat.gui

I started working with dat.GUI a few weeks ago and I know how to make a simple button which will visually span across a whole row in the GUI. Now I need a 'Browse' button which will have a non-clickable label in front of it which will contain some other text. I use something like this to create the button:

```
    var gui = new dat.GUI({autoPlace: true});
    gui.Browse = false;
    var browseButton = {
        Browse: function () {
        //browse logic
        }
    }
    gui.add(browseButton, 'Browse');
```

The button will take up a whole row in the dat.GUI. Is it possible to insert a label in front of it so they both fit into the same row?

Comment: It should be possible, but it would help if you showed a bit more code.

Comment: I've updated the code and explained a little bit more about what I need. Any help would be greatly appreciated.